# Users with identical names

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Apparently, nothing prevents the users from having identical display names (since they are assigned different userID): [here is another Vadim](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/224006/vadim). I admit though that this name is not a particularly rare one, so I will have to think of a better nickname. Has anyone else been in a similar situation? How did you handle it?

**Update:**

```
Vadim --> Roger Vadim
```

Comment: There are *pages* of users with common first names as their user name, type e.g. 'rob' into the search box [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users).

Comment: I suppose I will just change the name, but keep Vadim in it, so that it remains recognizable.

Comment: I used my forename and surname.

Comment: @JohnRennie People from science will look right away where you work/worked and how many publications you have.

Comment: I dealt with this by winning a moderator election and getting a diamond attached to my name.

Comment: Moderator flex xD @rob

Comment: @RogerVadim - since a little sleuthing will allow one moderately skilled in the art to find out way more than you imagine about anyone, giving a few hints doesn’t really change things. Anonymity only holds up when people don’t actually care who you are.

Comment: I used to have my full name as my username. Then another user started being kind of creepy towards me, hence my username now. In any case, you are a fairly regular user here, so I don't think there is an issue of getting you mixed up with the user you linked to.

Comment: @rob You beat me to the joke. ;)

Comment: Clearly, if I want to be a mod I need to shorten my name to just Jon…

Answer (score 6):

It's not much of a problem. While there may be users sharing a display name with you (many, if your name is Chris or rob), it's unlikely there are other *prominent* users that share a display name with you. As [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1411434/find-prominent-users-with-duplicate-names?minrep=1000) shows, there aren't many names with two high-rep users, and several of these appear to be alternate accounts of the same person.

For example, even though there are 173 users named "Chris," (ignoring case sensitivity), the next-highest reputation "Chris" has only 804 reputation and hasn't been active in years.

Comment: That query is not trivial to understand. Can you update the description with an explanation of the columns?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sure. How is it now?

Comment: Yep, that's better. Note that there is a dedicated `description` field, though.